# working with binary data and unsigned char

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a program that reads a content of a binary file (specificly Windows PE file. [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) and [detailed PE structure](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/corkami/pics/master/binary/pe101/pe101l.png)).
Because of the binary data in the file, the characters often "fall out" of the ascii range (0-127) and that result in negative values.

To make sure I won't work with unwanted negative values, I can either pass `const unsigned char *` or convert the resulting char in the calculation to `unsigned char`.

On one hand, passing `const unsigned char *` makes sense because the data is non-ascii that has a numaric value and thus should be treated as positive.
In addition, it'll let me perform calculations without the need to cast the result to `unsigned char`.
On the other hand, I can't pass constant strings (`const char *`, such as pre-defined strings "MZ", "PE\0\0" etc.) to functions without first casting them to `const unsigned char *`.

What would be the better approach or best-practice in this scenario?

Comment: It does not matter. When you work with binary data use fixed length types like uint8_t

Comment: Whichever way allows you to do the least casting is superior.  Unless you are allowing these to be sign-extended to ints, it will make no difference.

Comment: @P__J__ well, the specific case that made me ask it was the UnpackWord function that gets a char* and returns `WORD`. The data is read off a file so it has to go through _some_ processing as data before it is used.

Comment: I do not know what "magic" `UnpackWord` function does :) C does not have the `WORD` type. Is it uint32_t?

Comment: @P__J__It's defined in the Windows.h header, it's defined as unsigned short. this function should be a minimal version of python's unpack. it's basically return an unsigned 2-byte value from a 2-char string

Comment: "specificly a PE file" is not specific enough.  Post a refence like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable or whatever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd use `unsigned char`, but avoid casting, and instead define a little class named `ustring` (or something similar). You have a couple of choices with that. One would be to instantiate `std::basic_string` over `unsigned char`. This can be useful (it gives you all of `std::string`'s functionality, but with `unsigned char`s instead of `char`s. The obvious disadvantage is that it's probably overkill, and has essentially no compatibility with `std::string`, even though it's almost exactly the same thing.

The other obvious possibility would be to define your own class. Since you apparently care mostly about string literals, I'd probably go this way. The class would be initalized with a string literal, and it would just hold a pointer to the string, but as `unsigned char *` instead of just `char *`.

Then there's one more step to make life better: define a user defined literal operator named something like `_us`, so creating an object of your type from a string literal will look something like this: `auto DOS_sig = "MZ"_us;`

```
class ustring {
    unsigned char const *data;
    unsigned long long len;
public:
    ustring(unsigned char const *s, unsigned long long len) 
        : data(s)
        , len(len)
    {}

    operator char const *() const { return data; }

    bool operator==(ustring const &other) const {
        // note: memcmp treats what you pass it as unsigned chars.
        return len == other.len && 0 == memcmp(data, other.data, len);
    }

    // you probably want to add more stuff here.
};

ustring operator"" _us(char const * const s, unsigned long long len) {
    return ustring((unsigned char const *)s, len);
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, this should be pretty easy to work with. For example, let's assume you've memory mapped what you think is a PE file, with its base address at `mapped_file`. To see if it has a DOS signature, you might do something like this:

```
if (ustring(&mapped_file[0], 2) == "MZ"_us)
    std::cerr << "File appears to be an executable.\n";
else
    std::cerr << "file does not appear to be an executable.\n";
```

Caution: I haven't tested this, so fencepost errors and such are likely--for example, I don't remember whether the length passed to the user defined literal operator includes the NUL terminator or not. This isn't intended to represent finished code, just a sketch of a general direction that might be useful to explore.